# Dropdown box to change text in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

About me:
HTML experience: low
javascript experience: none
jQuery experience: none

I've got the following code and what I want happen is to have the text in the divText change depending on the option selected in dropBox. The function changeSelect relates the option value to what should be displayed in divText.

This doesn't work on ie7 or Chrome v38 (work notebooks, not allowed to update to newer version of ie).

I can't get the text to change but the values (in dropBox) are being read. If i take off the;

```
$(...);
```

around the function template, dropBox doesn't work/can't change selection from the default option.

Here's my code below;

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
/*  TEMPLATE CONTROL */

$(function changeSelect() {
if (document.getElementById("dropBox").value = "1") {
    document.getElementById("divText").innerhtml = "...";
} else if (document.getElementById("dropBox").value = "2") {
    document.getElementById("divText").innerhtml = "[HEADER] [DATE] [COUNT] ...";
} else if (document.getElementById("dropBox").value = "3") {
    document.getElementById("divText").innerhtml = "[HEADER] ...";
} else if (document.getElementById("dropBox").value = "4") {
    document.getElementById("divText").innerhtml = "NOTE [DATE] ...";
}
});


</script>

</head>

<body>

<!--TEMPLATE-->
<form action="">
<select type="text" id="dropBox" onchange="changeSelect()"> 
<option value="1">No Template</option>
<option value="2">Template 1</option>
<option value="3">Template 2</option>
<option value="4">Template 3</option>
</select>

<div id="divText">THIS TEXT SHOULD CHANGE</div>
<!--GENERATE BUTTON DOES NOTHING RIGHT NOW-->
<button onclick="">Generate</button>
</form>
<br>
<br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The property name is `innerHTML` and not `innerhtml`. JavaScript is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several issues here. Firstly, `=` is used for value assignment and `==` should be used for equality comparison. You need to change the `=` in your `if` statements to `==`.

Secondly, the property is called `innerHTML`, not `innerhtml` - note the capitalisation as JS is case-senstitve.

Lastly, you do not need the `$(..)` around your code. The issues were caused by the above problems.

Try this:

```
function changeSelect() {
    if (document.getElementById("dropBox").value == "1") {
        document.getElementById("divText").innerHTML = "...";
    } else if (document.getElementById("dropBox").value == "2") {
        document.getElementById("divText").innerHTML = "[HEADER] [DATE] [COUNT] ...";
    } else if (document.getElementById("dropBox").value == "3") {
        document.getElementById("divText").innerHTML = "[HEADER] ...";
    } else if (document.getElementById("dropBox").value == "4") {
        document.getElementById("divText").innerHTML = "NOTE [DATE] ...";
    }
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/syo72uL5/)

---

As you have tagged your question with jQuery, here is a jQuery (and also slightly optimised) version:

```
<select type="text" id="dropBox"> 
    <option value="1">No Template</option>
    <option value="2">Template 1</option>
    <option value="3">Template 2</option>
    <option value="4">Template 3</option>
</select>

<div id="divText">THIS TEXT SHOULD CHANGE</div>
```

```js
$(function() {
    var textOptions = ['...', '[HEADER] [DATE] [COUNT] ...', '[HEADER] ...', 'NOTE [DATE] ...'];
    $('#dropBox').change(function() {
        $('#divText').text(textOptions[parseInt($(this).val(), 10)]);
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/syo72uL5/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the insight Rory. Being out of the coding game for 10 years makes catching up a difficult task but thanks for pointing out the errors and explaining how they can be overcome. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

and this is how you could do it the `jQuery`way:

**HTML:**

```
<select type="text" id="dropBox">
    <option value="1">No Template</option>
    <option value="2">Template 1</option>
    <option value="3">Template 2</option>
    <option value="4">Template 3</option>
</select>
<div id="divText">THIS TEXT SHOULD CHANGE</div>
```

**Javascript / jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $("#dropBox").on("change", function () {
        switch ($(this).val()) {
            case "1":
                $("#divText").html("html/text for option 1");
                break;
            case "2":
                $("#divText").html("html/text for option 2");
                break;
            case "3":
                $("#divText").html("html/text for option 3");
                break;
            case "4":
                $("#divText").html("html/text for option 4");
                break;
        }
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/northkildonan/uj6ujoun/1/)